# Kotlin - How do I sum specific element in list?

Tags: kotlin

```
val total = mutableListOf("NO", "NO", "1", "2", "3", "4")
```

I want to sum which only can cast to int

In this case "1", "2", "3", "4"

Is there any quick way in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use `sumBy` like this:

```kotlin
total.sumBy { it.toIntOrNull() ?: 0 }
```